# Best way to create a user programatically

Tags: php, email, user-registration, scripts, wp-create-user

I want to create a user via a standalone script. I want an activation email to be sent out, in the same way that it is when a user is created from the Add User screen. An email is set out with a link to create the password. There is no password in the email.

There seem to be various functions for creating new users.

- [wp_insert_user](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user)
- [wp_create_user](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user)
- [register_new_user][3]

There's also

- wp-admin/user-new.php

Below is the code I have. It creates a new user, but it isn't the notification email. I've checked that wp-mail() and php mail() are working correctly.

I'm not sure that this is the right direction. I feel there might be an easier way to do it. If this is the right direction, any pointers on why the notification is not being sent?

Thanks.

```
<?php
define( 'SHORTINIT', true );
require_once( '/var/www/html/mysite/wp-load.php' );
require_once ('/var/www/html/mysite/wp-includes/user.php');
require_once ('/var/www/html/mysite/wp-includes/formatting.php');
require_once ('/var/www/html/mysite/wp-includes/capabilities.php');
require_once ('/var/www/html/mysite/wp-includes/pluggable.php');
require_once ('/var/www/html/mysite/wp-includes/kses.php');
require_once ('/var/www/html/mysite/wp-includes/meta.php');
function __() {}
wp_create_user ( 'testuser8', 'apsswd', 'someone@gmail.com' );
wp_new_user_notification ( testuser8,null,'both' );
?>
```

Answer (score 7):

You should [read the codex page re wp_create_user](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user).

You don't describe the context in which your code runs. 
You shouldn't need all those `require_once` calls.

Anyhow, in this line `wp_new_user_notification ( testuser8,null,'both' );` what is `testuser8` ?  It's not a variable, it's not a string, it's just some text that probably throws an error.

Try:

```
$user_id = wp_create_user ( 'testuser8', 'apsswd', 'someone@gmail.com' );
if( is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) 
    var_dump( $user_id );
else
    wp_new_user_notification ( $user_id, null,'both' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did have the username in quotes in my tests, but as you point out I was passing in the username, not the id.

I would like not to have all of the require_once calls, and in  fact I've had to add some more to get it working.

The script is run outside of the WP environment. It's a standalone script on the server. I haven't seen any description of how to load the entire environment, so I added them one-by-one as the script was failing with undefined function calls.

Comment: I've got rid of the require_once calls by using this, instead  `define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);  
require('/var/www/html/andaluciamia/wp-blog-header.php');`

Answer (score 2):

Use WP-CLI's [User Create](https://wp-cli.org/commands/user/create/) and put in a script.

> `wp user create` - Create a user.

```
$ wp user create testuser8 someone@gmail.com --user_pass=apsswd--role=author --send-email
Success: Created user 3.
```